# Find row in pandas and update specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `id, uid, gid, tstamp`. I'm able to locate a specific row by doing `df[df['id'] == 12]` which gives:

```
     id   uid   gid    tstamp
711  12   CA    CA-1   47585768600
```

How can I update the value of `uid` and `gid` say from `CA` to `IN` and `CA-1` to `IN-1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and set values to `['IN','IN-1']`:

```
print (df)
     id uid   gid       tstamp
711  12  CA  CA-1  47585768600
711  15  CA  CA-1  47585768600

df.ix[df['id'] == 12, ['uid','gid']] = ['IN','IN-1']

print (df)
     id uid   gid       tstamp
711  12  IN  IN-1  47585768600
711  15  CA  CA-1  47585768600
```

Another solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.ix[df['id'] == 12, ['uid','gid']] = 
df.ix[df['id'] == 12, ['uid','gid']].replace({'CA':'IN'}, regex=True)

print (df)
     id uid   gid       tstamp
711  12  IN  IN-1  47585768600
711  15  CA  CA-1  47585768600
```

Comment: According to Pandas, `.ix` is deprecated. 
We're supposed to use `.loc` for label based indexing or `.iloc` for positional indexing.

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated